# Print out shell variables and "" in awk/sed script using echo/printf

Tags: bash, awk, sed, printf, echo

A printout question: We need to print out the following awk into a .sh file.  (Remove all the row that has "0" in the 12th column)

```
awk -F, '$12 != "0"' output.csv >> output2.csv
```

Here is our script (The case loop is necessary for another purpose. This is a small step of a bigger script.  Assume $TargetIDs=123):

```
case $TargetIDs in ($P1) echo "awk -F, '$12 != "0"' ${TargetIDs}_output.csv >> ${TargetIDs}_output2.csv" >> output.sh;

(*)  ;;

esac
```

This will print out the following in the "output.sh".  The "$1" in "$12" disappears : (

```
awk -F, '2 != "0"' 123_output.csv >> 123_output2.csv
```

We try an array:

```
 V="12"

 b=($V)

case $TargetIDs in ($P1) echo "awk -F, '${b[1]} != "0"' ${TargetIDs}_output.csv >> ${TargetIDs}_output2.csv" >> output.sh;

(*)  ;;

esac
```

This will print out the following in the "output.sh".  $12 disappear:

```
    awk -F, ' != 0' output.csv >> output2.csv
```

The second question is similar: we use a sed way:

We want to print out this sed:

```
    sed -i.temp '/"0"/d' 123_output.csv.temp
    mv 123_output.csv.temp 123_output.csv
```

Here is the script

```
    case $TargetIDs in ($P1) printf "sed -i.temp '/"0"/d' ${TargetIDs}_output.csv.temp\n mv ${TargetIDs}_output.csv.temp ${TargetIDs}_output.csv\n" >> output.sh ;;

    (*)  ;;

    esac
```

This will print out the following in the "output.sh":

```
sed -i.temp '/0/d' 123_output.csv.temp
mv 123_output.csv.temp 123_output.csv
```

The sed command becomes this in the "output.sh"

```
sed -i.temp '/0/d'
```

instead of

```
sed -i.temp '/"0"/d'
```

"" is gone in the "output.sh" and  hence all the rows that have zero will be removed by

```
sed -i.temp '/0/d'
```

Wonder if gurus might have some solutions for this?  Thanks!

Comment: `case` is not a loop.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
echo "awk -F, '\$12 != 0' ${TargetIDs}_output.csv >> ${TargetIDs}_output2.csv"
```

This of course assumes that you are treating column 12 as a numeric value.

Comment: Simply add a "\" and the problem is solved?! Amazing! May I know what does "\" mean here? Thanks!

Comment: @HenrySu Some characters have special meaning to the shell. One way to remove the special meaning is to put a backslash before the character. (It's a little more involved than that, actually; see [shell quoting](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/html_node/Quoting.html) ). Note that I also removed the double-quotes around the `0` since they ended and restarted your double-quoted string. If you like this answer, be sure to *accept* it.

Answer (score 0):

You need to watch your quoting. Inside double quotes, single quotes aren't special, but dollar signs are. The nice bit is that you can concatenate multiple quoted segments, so you can change between different quoting styles in the same parameter.

Try this:

```
echo "awk -F, '"'$12 != "0"'"' ${TargetIDs}_output.csv >> ${TargetIDs}_output2.csv"
```

If `TargetIDs` might include whitespace or shell metacharacters, you'd also want to insert some more quotes into the generated text:

```
echo "awk -F, '"'$12 != "0"'"' \"${TargetIDs}_output.csv\" >> \"${TargetIDs}_output2.csv\""
```

As per the discussion in the comments, there is a difference between:

```
awk -F, '$12 != "0"' output.csv >> output2.csv
```

and

```
awk -F, '$12 != 0' output.csv >> output2.csv
```

in the case that field 12 is `00`. However, neither are correct if you want to remove lines where the 12th field is `"0"`, which seems to be the point of your `sed` line in your second question. In order to catch that, you'd need:

```
awk -F, '$12 != "\"0\""' output.csv >> output2.csv
```

Make sure that you are using the correct version.

Comment: Or just remove the double-quotes from around the `0`.

Comment: @ooga: The problem is that `$1` being expanded. Has nought to do with the 0. And there is a difference between `$12 != "0"` and `$12 != 0`; the first will be true if `$12` is `00`.

Comment: Is there any way to accept both answers?  Both are so great and well-explained!